# How to find first non-zero element and last non-zero element & Trim it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas Df with 1.2 million rows *10 columns.

## For E.g my DF look like

```html
Index     Time  a   b   c
0         1     0   1   0
1         2     0   0   1
2         3     0.3 0   1.5
3         4     0   1   0
4         5     0   0   5  
5         6     1   0   0
6         7     0   0   0
7         8     0   1   5
```

I would like to eliminate rows of the data frame that are BEFORE the first non-zero index of column "a" AND AFTER the last non-zero index of column "a". In the case above the results should look like this:

## My Requirement

```html
Index         Time  a   b   c
    0         3     0.3 0   1.5
    1         4     0   1   0
    2         5     0   0   5  
    3         6     1   0   0
```

I found the same question posted [Same requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252264/how-to-find-first-non-zero-element-and-last-non-zero-element-and-trim-vector), But there he used R to do the operation...
How can I do it in python ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First compare column `a` for not equal by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html), then get cumulative sum, and compare again, create another mask by change order by `[::-1]` for swap order and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['a'].ne(0)
df = df[m.cumsum().ne(0) & m[::-1].cumsum().ne(0)]

print (df)
   Time    a  b    c
2     3  0.3  0  1.5
3     4  0.0  1  0.0
4     5  0.0  0  5.0
5     6  1.0  0  0.0
```

Solution working nice if only `0` values in column `a`:

```
print (df)
   Time  a  b  c
0     1  0  1  0
1     2  0  0  1
6     7  0  0  0
7     8  0  1  5

m = df['a'].ne(0)
df = df[m.cumsum().ne(0) & m[::-1].cumsum().ne(0)]
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Time, a, b, c]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another method using `df.iloc[]`

```
m=df[df.a.ne(0)]
df.iloc[m.index[0]:m.index[1]+1]

   Index  Time    a  b    c
2      2     3  0.3  0  1.5
3      3     4  0.0  1  0.0
4      4     5  0.0  0  5.0
5      5     6  1.0  0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's use `first_valid_index` and `last_valid_index` with `mask`:

```
mask = df2['a'].mask(df2['a'] == 0)
start = mask.first_valid_index()
end = mask.last_valid_index()
df2.loc[start:end]
```

Output:

```
       Time    a  b    c
Index                   
2         3  0.3  0  1.5
3         4  0.0  1  0.0
4         5  0.0  0  5.0
5         6  1.0  0  0.0
```

Comment: Nice, first_valid_index is a nice option. +1 :)

Comment: @anky_91  Thank you.   I appreciate the comment.